# jQuery delay function

Tags: jquery, animation, delay, fadein

I have some concept of how I might do this, but could really use an "optimizer" out there to tell me what to do, so it's done right.

This is my markup:

```
<span class="darkmark">
  <em class="active rnr">RR</em>
  <em class="apple">Apple Enthusiast</em>
  <em class="glasses">Glasses Wearer</em>
  <em class="html5">HTML5 User</em>
  <em class="wine">Wine Drinker</em>
</span>
```

It's just a list of little icons that I want to cycle through in a header on a personal size. Cute right?

I would like every 5 seconds or so for the active class to move to the next sibling. Once the all the em's have been cycled through it returns to the first and the process goes on ad infinum.

Just don't know how I might do it. I don't want any user interaction to trigger it (no hover/click) just once the page loads they start cycling.

I realize that these should be in an ul li structure and plan to make that adjustment shortly.

Comment: Why not use a jquery plugin like jquery-cycle?

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){do="stuff";},5000);` should do you just fine.

Comment: I really want to "do it myself" feeling like learning a bit. Also, don't want a 800 line .js file when I could have an 8 line file. :)

Comment: See Alnitak's answer. Just because it has a setTimeout() doesn't mean it would take up more than 10-15 lines. It just needs to be self-referencing, to keep the effect 'alive'.

Comment: my code now fixed with 'setInterval' instead of 'setTimeout'!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a very similar question a day or two ago although I can't find it now.  The solution I posted looked like:

```
var rotateSiblings = function() {
    var cur = $('.active');                    // find current "active", if any
    var next = $(cur).next();                  // find its next sibling
    if (next.length == 0) {                    // if there wasn't one...
        next = $('.darkmark').children().first(); // take the first one from the span
    }

    $(cur).removeClass('active');              // remove "active" from the current one
    $(next).addClass('active');                // and add it to the next one
}

setInterval(rotateSiblings, 5000);             // and do it all over every 5 seconds
```

EDIT - this code has been changed since first posting.  Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/raybellis/UHWfC/

Comment: @Alnitak - Yes, I noted you originally had 250 for your timeout, which would have given you a 1/4 second timeout. It looks good now. :)

Comment: actually I had a couple of minor mistakes which I spotted when I created the jsfiddle.

Comment: @Alnitak - That's true, I completely forgot about `setInterval();`.

Comment: fadeIn / Out is tricky because the default jQuery fadeOut sets `display: none` when it's finished.  I'll try and update the fiddle.

Comment: I've added a click to start / pause, but as I thought fadeOut() is somewhat harder.

Comment: ok, best way to handle that is to add jQuery UI's support for animated class changes.  I've update the fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: @Alnitak -- Works exactly like I need it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function change_active() {
    var elements = $('.darkmark em');
    var count = elements.length;
    var active = $('.darkmark em.active');
    var next = (active.index() + 1) % count;
    active.removeClass('active');
    $(elements.get(next)).addClass('active');
}
setInterval(change_active, 5000);
```

Look at it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/MXUSh/).

Comment: B-e-a-utiful. Any thought how I could take advantage of fadeIn and fadeOut on this?

Answer (score 1):

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/YDcps/)

```
var darkmarkRotate = function () {
    var $this = $('.darkmark'),
        $em = $this.find('em'),
        $active = $this.find('em.active'),
        $next = ($active.next('em').length) ? $active.next('em') : $em.first();

    $active.fadeOut(500);
    $next.delay(500).fadeIn(500);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $next.addClass('active');
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(darkmarkRotate, 5000);
};

darkmarkRotate();
```